# Debezium is very slow, how to improve?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

First time user of Debezium, I get only around 1000 messages per **MINUTE** in debezium ( Which is very slow compared to online benchmark ). No throttling on Kafka connect/ MySQL/ Kafka Broker, not sure what I am doing here. I will post the config here for reference.

Config of Kafka-Connect Worker:

````
-e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="quickstart" \
-e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-config" \
-e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-offsets" \
-e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-status" \
-e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
-e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
-e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
-e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
-e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="localhost" \
-e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1\
-e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1\
-e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1\```


Config of Kafka Debezium MySQL Connector
````

I use all default config for Kafka Debezium MySQL Connector

Comment: please also post your Debezium connector config.

Comment: please update your question and give more details about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to reconfigure connector with [Avro Serialization](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.6/configuration/avro.html) to reduce size of the messages and track schema changes. This should  give you very significant improvement.

> The **Avro binary format is compact and efficient**. Avro schemas make it
> possible to ensure that each record has the correct structure. Avro’s
> **schema evolution** mechanism **enables schemas to evolve**. **This is
> essential for Debezium** connectors, which dynamically generate each
> record’s schema to match the structure of the database table that was
> changed.

To see difference removal of the schema from each message will make in your case, without Avro and set up of the Schema Registry, set settings below to `false`. Do not use it this way in production.

> The default behavior is that the JSON converter includes the record’s
> message schema, which makes each record very verbose.
> If you want records to be serialized with JSON, consider setting the
> following connector configuration properties to `false`:
> `key.converter.schemas.enable`
> `value.converter.schemas.enable`.
> Setting these properties to `false` excludes the verbose schema information from each record.

See also: ["Kafka Connect Deep Dive – Converters and Serialization Explained"](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/)